# PHP if / if else statement not working as expected (Probably Simple)

Tags: php, if-statement

Ok, I am trying to do an IF / else IF statement that doesn't act as i would expect.
I am trying to check that a URL address someone enters for certain things.
The way I have done it is probably crap but I am not that good at programming.

All the IF parts work except for this bit if (strpos($URLcheck, "http://") == false)

It is supposed to check if the URL has http:// in it. But whether it does or doesn't it still acts exactly the same way.

I even tried forcing the http:// into the URL by stripping it of http:// or https://.

When I echo the variable ($URLcheck) , it shows the URL with the http://.....so why doesn't my code work?
Thanks

```
    $URL = htmlspecialchars($_POST["URL"]);

    $URLREMOVESarray = array('https//:', 'http//:');
    $URLhttp = str_replace($URLREMOVESarray, "", $URL);

    $URLcheck = "http://" . $URLhttp;

    $URLsearchcheck2 = 'property-profile/';

    $URLsearchcheckDomain = "domain";


    if (strpos($URL, $URLsearchcheck2) !== false) {

   echo "Test 1";
   }
   else if (strpos($URLcheck, "http://") == false) {
   echo "Test 2";
   echo $URLcheck;
   }
   else if (strpos($URLcheck, $URLsearchcheckDomain) == false) {

   echo "Test 3";
   }
   else if (strpos($URLcheck, $URLsearchcheckDomain) == true) {
         Continue1();
   }
```

Update: Still no solutions to why this doesn't work? I have even copy and pasted the code from this page and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should use **`===`** operator. [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Comment: you're forcing a replacement of *HTTPS* domain prefix with a http prefix. This is not a good method

Comment: `false` equals `0` if you make comparisons without forcing the same type. Compare something with the same type with `===` or `!==`

Comment: thanks for the info, I tried all the alternatives ==  === !== and none of them worked for some reason

Answer (score 3):

use the same `!== false` statement:

```
$URLcheck = 'http://www.google.com';
if (strpos($URLcheck, "http://") !== false) {
   echo "Test 2";
   echo $URLcheck;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that code. i tried that myself but it didn't work. I can understand why

Answer (score 2):

`strpos($URLcheck, "http://")` searches for "http://" in the `$URLcheck` string and returns its position if it's found. In your case, it is indeed found at position 0 (start of $URLcheck string).

If `strpos()` doesn't find what it's looking for, it returns a `false`, which is not the same as 0, even though it sometimes seems so in PHP. This is the source of confusion for many less-experienced php devs, I advise to at least take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Anyway, in your case, the `0` that `strpos` returns is then checked if it **equals** `false` (with `==`). But since `0` is an integer type and `false` is a boolean type, PHP has to convert the `0` to boolean and the best match for zero between `true` and `false` is obviously `false`. That's why your `if` statement behaves as it does, it's actually perfectly correct behaviour.

So what you need to do is check whether your `strpos()` output is **identical** to `false` instead of whether it equals it. You do this by simply adding another `=` to your condition, so it reads `strpos($URLcheck, "http://") == false`.

Comment: thanks for the great explanation. I tried this code too but it also didn't work for me. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

ok, nothing worked that I tried from the suggestions so I went with this code and it works. No idea why the other code wouldn't work

```
    $pos = strpos($URLhttp, 'example.com');

    if ($pos === false) {
    echo "Test 1";
    }
```